# How to execute javascript in Angular HTML files?

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I am trying to parse a date in angular client side, but when I try running client-side javascript code, I get an error of: `Property 'Date' does not exist on type`. Why can't I run js code in angular HTML files?

Here is an example:

```js
// myComponent.component.html
<code>{{Date.parse("Thursday Sep 12 2022")}}</code>
```

My desired result should be a div with an string of milliseconds

Comment: You can only access member properties, but can add a `Date = Date` member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways:

- first is to create inside class a property and use it in the template like

> ```
> export class TestComponent {
>   Date = Date
> }
> ```

and then inside template use it like

> {{Date.parse("Thursday Sep 12 2022")}}

- second is to create a function like

> ```
> export class TestComponent {
>   convertDate(data: string): Date {
>     return Date.parse(data);
>   }
> }}
> ```

and then inside template use it like

> {{convertDate("Thursday Sep 12 2022")}}

- third is to use pipes (standart ones like [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)) or create your own

> import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Pipe({ name: 'customDatePipe' })
> export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
> transform(value: string): Date {
> return Date.parse(data)
> .  }
> }

and then inside template use it like

> {{"Thursday Sep 12 2022" | customDatePipe)}}